# Third-order dispersion in glass, direction influence

Tags: optics, dispersion, non-linear-optics

I have learned that the third-order dispersion $\chi$ is a tensor with 81 elements. Nevertheless in glass one only has four elements, which either can be $x$ or $y$ (in this case).
Now there exist four combinations, 
$\chi_{xxxx}, \chi_{xyxy}, \chi_{xyyx}$ and $\chi_{xxyy}$. I do not understand how one get (from the direction of the first three electric fields) the fourth one. How do I calculate the final direction of the electric field (fourth value)?
Furthermore I saw that $\chi_{xyxy} =\chi_{yxxy}\neq\chi_{xxyy}$. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this solution (which was not mentioned) is is assumed that the glass is isotropic. Then according to (for example) Sutherland we have the three room dimensions $x$, $y$ and $z$ for the incoming electrical field. Now due to isotropy the 81-element-matrix only has 21 non-zero elements with 
$$\chi_{XXXX}=\chi_{YYYY}=\chi_{ZZZZ}$$
$$\chi_{XXYY}=\chi_{YYXX}=\chi_{XXZZ}=\chi_{ZZXX}=\chi_{YYZZ}=\chi_{ZZYY}$$
$$\chi_{XYXY}=\chi_{YXYX}=\chi_{XZXZ}=\chi_{ZXZX}=\chi_{YZYZ}=\chi_{ZYZY}$$
$$\chi_{YXXY}=\chi_{XYYX}=\chi_{XZZX}=\chi_{ZXXZ}=\chi_{ZYYZ}=\chi_{YZZY}$$
Every $\chi$ has to have a direction two or four times, otherwise the body is not isotropic (due to preferencing one certain direction over the inverted direction). Thus we can reduce the non-equal elements to 
$$\chi_{XXXX}\text{, }\chi_{XXYY}\text{, }\chi_{YXXY}\text{ and }\chi_{YXYX}$$
And finally we can add three of them up:
$$\chi_{XXXX} = \chi_{XXYY}+\chi_{YXYX}+\chi_{YXXY}$$
The last sentence in the question is therefore definitely wrong.